# How to use Aggregate method of Dictionary<> in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary, delegates, lambda, aggregate

I'm a beginner in C#. I have a dictionary like this :

```
{
  {"tom", "student"},
  {"rob", "teacher"},
  {"david", "lawyer"}
}
```

I want to form this line :

```
tom = student, rob = teacher, david = lawyer
```

I want to use Aggregate extension method of `dictionary<>` but when i do it like this :

```
Console.WriteLine(dic.Aggregate((a,b) => (a.Key + " = " + a.Value + ", " + b.Key + " = " + b.Value)));
```

I get this error :

> Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type.

So it seems that i'm doing it wrong. So can anybody tell me how to use this method?

Comment: I'm not posting this as an answer since you asked about the correct usage of `Aggregate`, but in this scenario I'd lean to towards the following: `string.Join(", ", dic.Select(x => string.Format("{0} = {1}", x.Key, x.Value)))`. Simply mapping each `kvp` into the desired string and calling `string.Join()` seems the simplest approach to me.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate.aspx) is not a method from Dictionary, it's an extension method for `IEnumerable<T>`. If you want to build aggregated string:

```
dic.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(),
              (sb, kvp) => sb.AppendFormat("{0}{1} = {2}", 
                           sb.Length > 0 ? ", " : "", kvp.Key, kvp.Value),
              sb => sb.ToString());
```

Explanation:

- First parameter is accumulator, which will accumulate result
- Second parameter is a function, which will be invoked on each dictionary element. This function appends data to accumulator.
- Last parameter builds result string from accumulator

By the way you can use following code to build required string:

```
String.Join(", ", dic.Select(kvp => kvp.Key + " = " + kvp.Value));
```

Comment: So if i want to form " WHERE name=tome, job=teacher" i would use :
`dic.Aggregate(" WHERE ",(sb, kvp) => sb.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value),sb => sb.ToString());`

Comment: You can use `dic.Aggregate(new StringBuilder("WHERE "), (sb, kvp) => sb.AppendFormat("{0}{1} = {2}", sb.Length > 6 ? ", " : "", kvp.Key, kvp.Value), sb => sb.ToString()));` But I'd generated parameters separately from and then created query string `String.Format("... WHERE {0}", parameters)`

Comment: Ah, got it!... I can't thank you enough really, this was giving me nightmares.